# Syntax for changing activerecord data type on command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, command-line, migration

I have an activerecord table called Procedures, with all of the columns as strings. I want to change one of the columns to float. What is the syntax for doing this on the command line? Is it something like:

```
rails g migration change_avg_submitted_charges_in_procedures_float
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will generate the migration file.  Then edit the file to read something like:

```
change_column :table_name, :column_name, :float
```

then run

```
rake db:migrate
```